# mysql_real_escape_string only escaping one type of quote

Tags: php, mysql, escaping, quotes, mysql-real-escape-string

My server is running PHP 5.2.17 and I have disabled magic quotes with a php.ini file. I have an array of strings some are like

abcd "efg" hij'k lmnop'q

I am escaping them for insertion into a mysql database using the following code

```
foreach($array as &$data) {
    mysql_real_escape_string($data);
}
```

I am then constructing my sql like so

```
$sql='INSERT INTO table VALUES('.
     '"'.$array[0].'", '.
     '"'.$array[1].'", '.
     '"'.$array[2].'")';
```

I get an error when I try to execute my query. I output the $sql variable when I get an error and it seems that mysql_real_escape_string is only escaping either single quotes or double quotes.

If my $sql variable is created using single quotes with the column values in double quotes like it is above then single quotes are escaped but double quotes are not.

If I switch the quotes so that the $sql variable is created using double quotes and the column values are in single quotes only the double quotes are escaped.

Can anyone figure out what might be going wrong?

**UPDATE

Matchu figured it out. I have changed my code to the following and it works:

```
foreach($row as &$data) {
    $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
}
```

Comment: You might want to look at [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), placeholders are kinda' nice.

Comment: A usage example of PDO can be found in NullUserException's answer *(shameless self-promotion)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mysql_real_escape_string` does *not* modify the string object itself, even if you use `&` to pass by reference instead of by value. Instead, it returns an escaped copy of the string. You can't just run the function; you have to assign its output to a variable.

I'm not in a place where I can test right now, but [Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/927652/joe) says this does the trick:

```
$data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
```

Comment: Code: `$data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);`

Comment: @Joe: thanks :) This box doesn't have PHP on it, and, since I'm not super-familiar with how PHP handles `&`, I didn't feel confident including a code block without being able to test it. I'll just quickly edit that in there, properly attributed, of course :)

Answer (score 3):

A better solution is to use [PDO prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO table VALUES(?, ?, ?)"); 
$stmt->execute($array);
```

No repeated calls to `mysql_real_escape_string()`, no iterating, and (IMO) cleaner code.

Answer (score 1):

Matchu is correct, mysql_real_escape_string returns the escaped string. Try...

```
foreach($array as &$data) {
   $data = mysql_real_escape_string( $data );
}
```

Good luck.